# how to fetch specific value from response header in angular interceptor

Tags: angular, http, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to use a value to check token is expired or not in interceptor. Token Expired value is coming in Response header.
[screenshot of response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdLfF.png)

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
  const reqWithCredentials = req.clone({withCredentials: true});
  return next.handle(reqWithCredentials)
    .pipe(map(resp => {
      // on Response
      if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // Do whatever you want with the response.
        return resp;
      }
    }),
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (error.status === this._appConstant.ErrorCodes.Unauthorized || error.status === this._appConstant.ErrorCodes.Forbidden) {
            if (error.headers.has('Token-Expired')) {
              this.router.navigate(["/tokenexpired"]);
            }
            else {
              this.router.navigate(["/unauthorized"]);
            }
          }
          else {
            return throwError(error);
          }
        }
      })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return next.handle(reqWithCredentials)
  .pipe(map(resp => {
    // on Response
    if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
           if(resp.headers.get('headerName')) {
                // Do whatever you want with the response.
             }
      return resp;
    }
  })
```